# Are ThreadLocals Started in an Async-Supported Filter Thread Safe

Tags: java, multithreading, filter, servlet-3.0, thread-local

in JSR 315 async-support for servlets and filters was added. Is a ThreadLocal created in such filter thread safe?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.app.filter.ResourceFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```

A filter

```
public class ResourceFilter implements Filter  {



private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try{
        String uri = WebUtilityHelper.getURI(request);
        boolean isAResource = WebUtilityHelper.isAResource(uri);
        ThreadLocalUtil.setIsResource(isAResource);
        log.trace("URI: {}, isAResource? {}", uri, isAResource);
    } finally {         
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {}
```

}

and the relevant part of the util. I am maintaining multiple hibernate sessions within this. without getting into detail this is in support of an application level sharding solution. multiple datasources sharing entities loaded under separate class loaders... managed by different session factories.

```
public class ThreadLocalUtil {

/* Contant static names */

private static final String HIBERNATE_ASYNC_SESSION = "hibernateAsyncSession";
private static final String HIBERNATE_GLOBAL_SESSION = "hibernateGlobalSession";



private static final String IS_RESOURCE = "isResource";

/* The Constant THREAD_VARIABLES */
private static final ThreadLocal<ThreadVariables> THREAD_VARIABLES = new ThreadLocal<ThreadVariables>() {

    /**
     * @see java.lang.ThreadLocal#initialValue()
     */
    @Override
    protected ThreadVariables initialValue() {
        return new ThreadVariables();
    }
};


public static Object get(String name) {
    return getThreadVariable(name);
}

/**
 * Gets the thread variable.
 *
 * @param name
 *            the name
 * @return the thread variable
 */
public static Object getThreadVariable(String name) {
    return THREAD_VARIABLES.get().get(name);
}    /**
 * Sets the thread variable.
 *
 * @param name
 *            the name
 * @param value
 *            the value
 */
public static synchronized void setThreadVariable(String name,
        Object value) {
    THREAD_VARIABLES.get().put(name, value);
}

/**
 * Destroy.
 */
public static void destroy() {
    closeAllHibernateSessions();
    THREAD_VARIABLES.remove();
}

public static void remove(String name) {
    THREAD_VARIABLES.get().remove(name);
}}
```

i think the part i'm really asking about is
Servlet 3.0 spec 2.3.3.4
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1455121502_a9b513ab9b8fc5ac5a82d0518e88f7ac

Comment: 'Are `ThreadLocals` thread-safe?' Yes. 'In an Async-supported Filter?' Irrelevant.

Comment: i think you are over simplifying a much more difficult question. obviously the thread local is safe when used in one thread. the question is really how does the async-support function? is the threadlocal bound to the filter or the thread the filter spawns.

Comment: It is bound to the thread it was created in. I think you at over-complicating a very simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async architecture is no different to sync in terms of whether a ThreadLocal is threadsafe or not ie. as long as references are not leaked to other threads then it's safe.

In your snippet, ie. assume (I cannot tell) that the implementation of `ThreadLocalUtil` is not doing anything dangerous.

BTW - There are some limitations in several containers for running  filter chain in async mode - see [this on Github](https://github.com/circlespainter/servlet3-filter-async-test#servlet-3-filter-chain-async-mode-test)

Comment: it is possible that something i have done with my session factories might be leaking references. the idea came from looking at spring / hibernate OpenSessionInViewFilter. using this concept i manipulate the connection factories. gives me the ability to connect to multiple datasource with the same entities... also write to master read from slave sort of architecture. from a L1/L2 cache perspective, since the tenant identifier is appended to the identifier key, provided my tenants remain unique across all shards,, that works out nicely.

Comment: Should have mentioned this a long time ago for others following this. Since connections from a JDBC connection pool are reused instead of destroyed, threadlocals used in this way will be bound to the connection not the request or thread started from the such a request. Clean threadlocals religiously both before and after use.